# LINQ Group-by with complete object access

Tags: c#, linq

What I want is better explained with code. I have this query:

```
var items = context.Items.GroupBy(g => new {g.Name, g.Model})
                .Where(/*...*/) 
                .Select(i => new ItemModel{
                                Name=g.Key.Name,
                                SerialNumber = g.FirstOrDefault().SerialNumber //<-- here
                                     });
```

Is there a better way to get the serial number or some other property that is not used in the key? The only way I could think of is to use FirstOrDefault.

Comment: By grouping, it returns a list of object. I don't really understand what is the problem there. Usually, when you groupby, you want to use the list, not only the first one (or last with `LastOrDefault`). What do you need to do (or need to know)?

Comment: @GabrielGM, I want to group the items by certain related properties, but when I'm selecting the objects, I want to access all properties of that Item and not just those in the `Key`. I did not group by Serial number so I cannot do `g.Key.SerialNumber`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just include the serial number as part of the key via the anonymous type you're declaring:

```
var items = context.Items.GroupBy(g => new {g.Name, g.Model, g.SerialNumber })
            .Where(/*...*/) 
            .Select(i => new ItemModel {
                    Name=g.Key.Name,
                    SerialNumber = g.FirstOrDefault().SerialNumber //<-- here
             });
```

Or, alternatively, make your object the key:

```
var items = context.Items.Where(...).GroupBy(g => g)
    .Select(i => new ItemModel {...});
```

Sometimes it can be easier to comprehend the query syntax (here, I've projected the `Item` object as part of the key):

```
var items = from i in context.Items
            group i by new { Serial = g.Serialnumber, Item = g } into gi
            where /* gi.Key.Item.GetType() == typeof(context.Items[0]) */
            select new ItemModel { 
                 Name = gi.Key.Name, 
                 SerialNumber = gi.Key.Serial 
                 /*...*/ 
            };
```

EDIT: you could try grouping after projection like so:

```
var items = context.Items.Where(/*...*/).Select(i => new ItemModel { /*...*/})
    .GroupBy(g => new { g.Name, g.Model });
```

you get an
    ``` IGrouping<AnonymousType``1, IEnumerable<ItemModel>> ``` from this with your arbitrary `group by` as the key, and your ItemModels as the grouped collection.

Comment: I don't want to group by the serial number, there are other properties other than the serial number I want in my model but not to group by.

Comment: so then group it by whatever you want AFTER you do your model projection - I'll edit my post w/ a demo

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly advise against what you're doing.  The serial number is being chosen arbitrarily since you do no ordering in your queries.  It would be better if you specified exactly which serial number to choose that way there are no surprises if the queries return items in a different ordering than "last time".

With that said, I think it would be cleaner to project the grouping and select the fields you need and take the first result.  They all will have the same key values so that will stay the same, then you can add on any other fields you want.

```
var items = context.Items.GroupBy(i => new { i.Name, i.Model })
    .Where(/*...*/) 
    .Select(g =>
        g.OrderBy(i => i.Name).Select(i => new ItemModel
        {
            Name = i.Name,
            SerialNumber = i.SerialNumber,
        }).FirstOrDefault()
    );
```

Comment: Thanks, your first paragraph made me see a flaw in my logic.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need all the data, you need to store all the group data into your value (in the KeyValuePair). 

I don't have the exact syntax in front of me, but it would look like:

```
/* ... */
.Select(g => new {
                     Key = g.key,
                     Values = g
                 });
```

After that, you can loop through the `Key` to get your `Name` group. Inside of that loop, include a loop through the `Values` to get your `ItemModel` (I guess that's the object containing 1 element).

It would look like:

```
foreach (var g in items) 
{ 
    Console.WriteLine("List of SerialNumber in {0} group", g.Key); 
    foreach (var i in g.Values) 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine(i.SerialNumber); 
    } 
}
```

Hope this helps!

You might want to look at [Linq 101 samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b) for some help on different queries.

Answer (score 0):

if the serial number is unique to the name and model, you should include it in your group by object.

If it is not, then you have a list of serials per name and model, and selecting firstordefault is probably plain wrong, that is, I can think of no scenario you would want this.

Comment: Because the Serial is not a key I want to group by.

Comment: unless I'm misunderstanding you, it seems like you do want to group by Serial: You want groups of unique (name, model, serial) tuples. If this is so, Serial is, in fact, a key you want to group by. If not, I don't understand what you want at all.